# jquery addClass isn't being applied in the right order

Tags: javascript, jquery, addclass

In my example below I add a class `busy` to the body immediately on click. This should turn the background red. I then remove this class after an each loop is complete.

What is in fact happening is that the class `busy` is being added once the loop is complete and then immediately removed. I know this is the case because if I remove the `removeClass` condition within the loop the class `busy` is added and stays added.I can not understand why. I've been stuck on this problem for over an hour and am at a complete standstill.

In the fiddle example click column 3.

Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/2nvopbqo/3/

```
$(".sort").click(function() {
  $('body').addClass('busy');
  var col = $(this).parent().children().index($(this));
  var desc = $(this).hasClass('desc');
  var date = $(this).hasClass('date');
  sortTable(desc, col, date);
  $(this).toggleClass("desc asc");
});

function sortTable(order, col, date) {
  var rows = $('#mytable tbody  tr').get();

  rows.sort(function(a, b) {

    var A = $(a).children('td').eq(col).text().toUpperCase();
    var B = $(b).children('td').eq(col).text().toUpperCase();

    if (date) {
      var A = A.split("-").reverse().join('-');
      var B = B.split("-").reverse().join('-');
    }

    if (order) {
      if (B < A) return -1;
      if (B > A) return 1;
    } else {
      if (A < B) return -1;
      if (A > B) return 1;
    }

    return 0;
  });

  var totalRows = rows.length;


  $.each(rows, function(index, row) {
    $('#mytable').children('tbody').append(row);

    if (index == totalRows - 1) $('body').removeClass('busy');
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code never yields back to the browser to allow it to show the updated state that adding the class causes before launching into the work and removing the class. Your main JavaScript code runs on a thread that's also used to update the UI (this is important for several reasons).

If you want to allow the class's effects to be seen, yield back to the browser with a `setTimeout` with a duration of 0 or a very small number (test with your target browsers, I've had to use ~40ms on Firefox on occasion):

```
$(".sort").click(function() {
  $('body').addClass('busy');
  var $this = $(this);
  setTimeout(function() {
    var col = $this.parent().children().index($(this));
    var desc = $this.hasClass('desc');
    var date = $this.hasClass('date');
    sortTable(desc, col, date);
    $this.toggleClass("desc asc");
  }, 40);
});
```

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2nvopbqo/5/) (since there's no way I'm putting all of that HTML in an answer).

Comment: You may need 50ms or something to make it work on all the browsers. FF seems to not react on 1ms

Answer (score 0):

All changes that force a repaint are only applied once the current function is done. Since your click handler both adds and then removes the `.busy` tag, the change isn't done. Making the sort call 'async' will fix this.

```
$(".sort").click(function() {
  $('body').addClass('busy');
  var col = $(this).parent().children().index($(this));
  var desc = $(this).hasClass('desc');
  var date = $(this).hasClass('date');
  //will fire after the click handler is done.
  setTimeout(sortTable,0,desc, col, date); 
  // you could also use requestAnimationFrame
  $(this).toggleClass("desc asc");
});
```